# FeatureTools: Can there be multiple columns in time_index parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetimeindex, featuretools

I have 2 time paramaters in a dataframe i.e. start_date and end_date and both are time parameters when one creates a entityset from a dataframe.

While specifying the time_index, can we specify 2 different columns?

I don't want to create a new column which merges the 2 columns as I want to get the agg_primitives like "time_since_first", "time_since_last", "avg_time_between", "trend" for both the columns.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by assigning the second time column as a `DatetimeTimeIndex`. Here is an example using a demo dataset.
​

```py
import featuretools as ft
​
df = ft.demo.load_mock_customer(return_single_table=True)
df = df.filter(regex='amount|customer|time')
```

​
I create the second time column.
​

```py
df['transaction_time_2'] = df['transaction_time']
df.head()
```

```
     transaction_time  amount  customer_id  transaction_time_2
0 2014-01-01 00:00:00  127.64            2 2014-01-01 00:00:00
1 2014-01-01 00:09:45   57.39            2 2014-01-01 00:09:45
2 2014-01-01 00:14:05   69.45            2 2014-01-01 00:14:05
3 2014-01-01 02:33:50  123.19            2 2014-01-01 02:33:50
4 2014-01-01 02:37:05   64.47            2 2014-01-01 02:37:05
```

​
Then, I create an entity set. I use the `variable_types` parameter to set my second time column as a `DatetimeTimeIndex` variable type.
​

```py
es = ft.EntitySet()
es.entity_from_dataframe(
    'transactions',
    df,
    time_index='transaction_time',
    index='id',
    make_index=True,
    variable_types={
        'transaction_time_2': ft.variable_types.DatetimeTimeIndex,
    }
)
es.normalize_entity('transactions', 'customers', index='customer_id')
```

​
Lastly, I calculate the feature matrix. We can see that the time-based primitves were applied to both time columns.
​

```py
fm, fd = ft.dfs(
    target_entity='customers',
    entityset=es,
    agg_primitives=[
        "time_since_first",
        "time_since_last",
        "avg_time_between",
        "trend",
    ],
    trans_primitives=[],
)
​
print(fm.iloc[0].to_string())
```

```
TIME_SINCE_FIRST(transactions.transaction_time)      1.822703e+08
TIME_SINCE_FIRST(transactions.transaction_time_2)    1.822703e+08
TIME_SINCE_LAST(transactions.transaction_time)       1.822401e+08
TIME_SINCE_LAST(transactions.transaction_time_2)     1.822401e+08
AVG_TIME_BETWEEN(transactions.transaction_time)      3.285326e+02
AVG_TIME_BETWEEN(transactions.transaction_time_2)    3.285326e+02
TREND(transactions.amount, transaction_time)        -5.251887e+01
TREND(transactions.amount, transaction_time_2)      -5.251887e+01
```

​
Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks this helps and solves the problem. Had a query though: Why don't you create a new relationship as compared to normalize entity? What is the difference  between the two?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. The relationship is created automatically with `normalize_entity`. I'd suggest looking through [this example](https://docs.featuretools.com/loading_data/using_entitysets.html#creating-entity-from-existing-table) in the documentation.