# How to create features for multiple datetime columns in featuretools?

Tags: python, featuretools

Sorry to put three question in one issue.

1. How to create features for **multiple datatime columns**?

   I got a dataframe with multiple datetime columns, and hoped to create features like TimeSinceFirst, TimeSinceLast for all of them. But with only one of them set as time_index, I couldn't get time-related features for the others with DFS.
   I found a related post which seems deprecated now: [FeatureTools: Can there be multiple columns in time_index parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58156703/featuretools-can-there-be-multiple-columns-in-time-index-parameters)
2. Is there any (performance) **difference between DFS and calculate_feature_matrix**?

   While I got to do DFS for different entitysets of the same structure, is there any preference for the following two methods:

   - Just DFS repeatedly;
   - DFS and save feature definitions for the frist time, and then calculate_feature_matrix with saved definitions for the following entitysets.
3. Why couldn't I **suppress RuntimeWarning** when DFS, and how to make it?

   Tons of RuntimeWarning printed when running

   ```
   with warnings.catch_warnings():
       warnings.simplefilter(action="ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)
       ft.dfs(...)
   ```

   ```
   /.../python3.9/site-packages/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py:1117: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice
     return np.nanmean(a, axis, out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
   ```

Any idea is highly appreciated! Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

I asked [almost the same questions on github](https://github.com/alteryx/featuretools/issues/2321), and have got answers to the first two there. In summary,

1. How to create features for **multiple datatime columns**?

   You should create custom primitives to make it. To quote from [here](https://github.com/alteryx/featuretools/issues/2321#issuecomment-1284587496), "For the custom primitive you could copy the code for TimeSinceLast and just remove `semantic_tags={"time_index"}` from `input_types = [ColumnSchema(logical_type=Datetime, semantic_tags={"time_index"})]`."
2. Is there any (performance) **difference between DFS and calculate_feature_matrix**?

   It's prefereed to DFS and save feature definitions for reuse. Please refer to [the details](https://github.com/alteryx/featuretools/issues/2321#issuecomment-1276801299).